# Class cannot be resolved to a variable equals method

Tags: java, equals

I am a Java beginner and I was trying to implement an equals method in an Address Class that I have made.

```
public class Address {
protected String validFrom;
protected String validTo;

 public boolean equals(Object otherObject) {
    if(otherObject == null)
        return false;
    else if
        (getClass( ) != otherObject.getClass( ))
        return false;
    else
        Address otherAddress = (Address) otherObject;
        return (validFrom.equals(otherAddress.validFrom) && validTo.equals(otherAddress.validTo));
}
```

**However I am getting an error at**

```
Address otherAddress = (Address) otherObject;
```

**The error is :**

> Address cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: Use curly braces in your if else statements and it will be ok. Your return statements in `else if` and `else` block are out of scope.

Comment: while this doesn't answer the question, here's a better equals() implemenation for you: [ta-dah](https://pastebin.com/cBa0zXik) - better because if yours will throw NPE if `validTo` or `validFrom` are null when calling `.equals()` on a non-null Address object.